# Exponentiation Recursive

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-science

I am learning this Exponentiation Recursive algorithm, it works well.
But I don't understand why this works?
Because I expect that always returns 1,1,1...if `n` is even because a doesn't multiply in the `return`.
When I try `recPower(3,2)`, and print the factor step by step, it will be like:

1
3
9

But, why does 3 come out?

```
 def recPower(a, n):
     # raises a to the int power n
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        factor = recPower(a, n//2)
        if n%2 == 0: # n is even
            return factor * factor
        else:        # n is odd
            return factor * factor * a
```

Comment: The 3 is there because 1*1*3 == 3

Comment: Your algorithm implements precisely this: `a**(2*n) = (a**n) * (a**n)`, `a**(2*n+1) = (a**n) * (a**n) * a`. What exactly don't you understand about it?

Comment: "because a doesn't multiply in the return" Depending on what you exactly mean by that, I'd say it does in the bottom return: `return factor * factor * a`.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. It returns 'a' when n == 1. I just thought that when initial n starts even, it will never return  'a'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow it step by step:

```
recPower(3, 2)
```

`n != 0` so go down the else branch:

```
factor = recPower(3, 2//2)
```

Which is:

```
recPower(3, 1)
```

In this recursive step `n != 0` we follow the first else branches, `1%2 != 0` so we follow the second else branch. The factor is therefore 1 and `a` == 3.

The return value of this step is therefore:

```
factor * factor * a
```

or

```
1 * 1 * 3
```

Comment: Thank you, I totally forget the `n` will be equal to 1, and invoke the latter `return`. I just focus too much in the initial `n` value.